# Why does visual studio 2022 publish not just copy everything in Release directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2022

I have setup vs 2022 with a file publish profile. The first time I ran publish it did not copy unreferenced dlls. So I had to add all unreferenced projects to the project. Ran publish again, found it does not run post-build events in projects. That leaves me with doing this in the asp.net core project:

```
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="wwwroot/graphics\**" />
      <Content Include="..\..\..\..\..\bin\Release\x64\**">
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </Content>
      <Content Include="..\..\..\..\..\bin\Release\x86\**">
          <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

In order to get a couple of directories created during a post-build event.

Then when I publish it says there is a file conflict:

```
Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path: 
  C:\Repo\My\Libraries\Vendor\Product\my.dll, 
  C:\Repo\My\bin\Release\x64\my.dll, 
  C:\Repo\My\bin\Release\x86\my.dll.
```

From the relative path this should only see C:\Repo\My\bin not C:\Repo\My\Libraries.

Why is publish looking in C:\Repo\My\Libraries and not just C:\Repo\My\bin. I have the sln setup to bring in everything I need and no more. Can publish be setup to just do copy of all folders and files in C:\Repo\My\bin\Release?

Should I not use publish and just do xcopy, because right now I don't see the value in publish.

Answer (score -1):

\bin is the default location where VS places native builds, not published files. Builds in this location rely on the OS having the needed .NET installed.

\obj is the default location for Publishing. Here, you can set Publish to be self-contained or use a different runtime, etc.

In essence you are trying to publish to the Build folder. Which, while confusing, you would need to set the Build folder to be somewhere else. That could be done in the Project properties.

Comment: Your description of the `\bin` and `\obj` folders seems completely wrong. Can you provide some authoritative source of this information?